# ServiceStack Incompatible net 4.7.1

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, servicestack

i have a problem with VS2017 (15.4.2) and ServiceStack.

The error is the seguent:
Package ServiceStack.Logging.Log4Net 4.5.14 is not compatible with net471 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1) / win-x64. Package ServiceStack.Logging.Log4Net 4.5.14 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5).

I tried all the roads, reinstalling VS, reinstalling Dot net, disabling and reinstalling the Plugin Servicestack without any success. I am short of ideas.
The operating system is W10.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's a W10 problem in version 1703. I updated the operating system with version 1709 everything is back to work

Answer (score 0):

Don't see why a .NET v4.5 binary would be incompatible with .NET v4.7 but you can avoid the ServiceStack.Logging.Log4Net dependency by manually copying the [Log4NetFactory.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Logging.Log4Net/Log4NetFactory.cs) and [Log4NetLogger.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Logging.Log4Net/Log4NetLogger.cs) files into your project, which is all the .cs files the ServiceStack.Logging.Log4Net NuGet package contains.

Comment: I believe it is a nuget bug where the package fails some compat check (e.g. dll files in unexpected locations - satellite resource assemblies for example) and the wrong error message is displayed.